# How to space images evenly and add text below them

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, responsive

It has been quite some time since I ever had to use HTML or CSS. I am trying to to add 3-4 images in a horizontal line along with some text below each of them. I would like each image + text to be spaced evenly and also have them stack vertically when the browser is resized. What is the best way to go about this? My code right now is absolute crap and I honestly don't know where to begin.

```
<style><!--
#container {
  height: 125px;
  text-align: justify;
  -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.box4 {
  width: 150%;
  height: 125%;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1
}

.stretch {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0
}

--></style>
<div id="container">

<div class="box1"><img src="img" /><b text-align="center">Test for bold header</b><br />
<p>This is a bunch of test text to see if the text will actually center below the image</p>
</div>

<div class="box2"><img src="img" width="200px" />
<p>This is a bunch of test text to see if the text will actually center below the image</p>
</div>

<div class="box3"><img src="img" width="200px" />
<p>This is a bunch of test text to see if the text will actually center below the image</p>
</div>

<div class="box4"><img src="img" width="200px" />
<p>This is a bunch of test text to see if the text will actually center below the image</p>
</div>
 
<span class="stretch"></span></div>
```

I am sure there is a MUCH simpler way to do this that doesn't require all of this crap code I pieced together. I am trying to mimic something like this https://tomorrowslaundry.co/pages/essentials-club-welcome?sscid=81k5_bf9d1& under the section "Why it works"

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  and

tags for text use fig caption it will automatically center the text below the image.
For stacking images horizontally and vertically with even spacing use display: flex and flex-direction property. For also see justify-content and align-items properties for equal spaceing.

Ref:

1. Figcaption : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp
2. Flex properties : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex` on the ***flex parent*** then on each ***flex child*** add a `display:flex` and set as `flex-direction: column;` to place your text below each image then separate by `justify-content: space-between;` to place each ***flex child*** element at opposing **start** and **end** of ***flex parent*** ***image***. Add a `max-width` equal to the ***percentage*** of elements you wish to place in your initial ***flex parents*** row.

Edit: Added a *media query* for max screen size 500px to show how to place images stacked on top of each other when screen size is certain size.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.box2~.box2 {
  margin-left: .2rem;
}

.box2 {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: .5rem;
  }
  .box2 {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .box2 ~ .box2 {
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box2">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/100/any">
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/100/any">
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/250/100/any">
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/100/any">
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you make the elements stack on to each other when the screen is resized?

Comment: You can place a media query and then change the flex-direction to column at the break point you want.